# Packaging winpexpect with pyinstaller

Tags: python, pyinstaller, software-packaging

I've attempted to create a pretty basic executable with pyinstaller, but when I run it winpexpect (a windows version of pexpect) throws me a pretty undecipherable error. I've really only been able to deduce that the error occurs when using the winspawn class.

```
C:\Users\Dan\Dropbox\Programming\Python\MC\ServerSense>ServerSense.exe
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 170, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 52, in __init__
  File "C:\Users\Dan\Dropbox\Programming\Python\Packagers\PyInstaller\PyInstalle
r-2.1\ServerSense\build\ServerSense\out00-PYZ.pyz\winpexpect", line 346, in __in
it__
  File "C:\Users\Dan\Dropbox\Programming\Python\Packagers\PyInstaller\PyInstalle
r-2.1\ServerSense\build\ServerSense\out00-PYZ.pyz\pexpect", line 429, in __init_
_
  File "C:\Users\Dan\Dropbox\Programming\Python\Packagers\PyInstaller\PyInstalle
r-2.1\ServerSense\build\ServerSense\out00-PYZ.pyz\winpexpect", line 401, in _spa
wn
pywintypes.error: (2, 'CreateProcess', 'The system cannot find the file specifie
d.')
```

Can anyone provide some insight as to how I'd go about packaging winpexpect with pyinstaller? It doesn't even seem to be letting me know which file it can't find.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, I used the fork of winpexpect over here: https://bitbucket.org/weyou/winpexpect/wiki/Home

Which has cx_freeze support, (py2exe works too, it's what I used.)

Comment: I'm having the same problem, the link you provide it's not updated... Do you know how I can solve this now?

Comment: Hey Bemojo, it's been 9 years and I no longer have the files related to this project. Best of luck solving your issue. Perhaps you could use the internet archive to determine what happened to the project linked above.